# How to use tomcat as a file server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat6

I have deployed a folder named mycontent to TOMCAT_HOME\webapps folder. My server is running on port 8080 . 
When I try to navigate to the folder using `http://localhost:8080/mycontent` the folder I receive a "HTTP Status 404" error. How can I use Tomcat to share the files within a folder in webapps ?

I don't think I need to add a context as the folder is in webapps and should be served automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To allow directory browsing via Apache Tomcat change the listings parameter in the file conf/web.xml from false to true."

Quoted from :  http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html

If tomcat is configured like so :

[image]

Add the app to `\WORKSPACE_DIR\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\webapps`

instead of webapps dir in TOMCAT_HOME

Comment: Why would you assume they're running Tomcat from within Eclipse?